# Exclude when parent has class

Tags: jquery

trying to exclude a set of elements from the matched set when it's parent object has a cetain class.

current solution is:

```
$("#pages li a").not($(this).parent().hasClass('no-script'))
```

but this is not behaving as I would expect, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here you want to exclude li with no-script class, right?

Comment: Could you post the html and advise what you are trying to do.

Comment: right, the answer given works. Just have to wait the allowed time to accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use a [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) on the parent, like this:

```
$("#pages li:not(.no-script) a")
```

If there many be multiple levels, make sure it's the current level's parent by using a [child selector (`>`)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$("#pages li:not(.no-script) > a")
```